# Inputting integers into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

If I have a line of integers in a text file in the following format: 
[3, 3, 5, 0, 0]
how can I go about adding the integers into an arraylist?
I have this, but it isn't working:

```
while (input.hasNextInt())

{
    int tempInt = input.nextInt();
    rtemp.add(tempInt);
}
```

How do I deal with the commas and the brackets?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ReplaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to remove the brackets and then use [Split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function to split the string into an ArrayList using ", " as your delimiter. This will however split the String into smaller strings containing only the numbers so use Integer.parseInt() to convert the string to int.

Comment: If he's using regex, he can just read those ints all off from scratch. No need for 2 passes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember that the numbers in a file are *strings*, and need to be converted to actual integers first. Assuming that in the input file each line has the format described (example: `[3, 3, 5, 0, 0]`) this should work for adding all of the numbers to a single `ArrayList`, ignoring spaces, brackets and commas:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String line = in.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    String[] numbers = line.split("[\\[\\],\\s]+");
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++)
        ints.add(Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]));
    line = in.readLine();
}

in.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested but this should work.

```
string s = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

foreach (string st in s.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(','))
{
     list.Add(int.Parse(st));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the entire string and use regular expression or also the string tokenizer

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);  

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {  
      String line = scanner.nextLine();  
      String[] nums = line.substring(1,line.length() - 1).split(",");  
      for(String n:nums){  
            list.add(Integer.valueOf(n));
      }
}
```

You could also use a regex for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
//you already know how to read those lines into Strings. 
String s="[3, 3, 5, 0, 0]";
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "[,]");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
 list.add(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken())
```

java.util.StringTokenizer will help you in splitting the String using the specified delimiters("[","," or a "]")

Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html